# Get status deploying package powershell on Azure

Tags: powershell, azure

I deploy package to staging of cloud service. I what write powershell script, which waiting, when package have been finished to deploying. In web site I can see next message:

```
    Deploying
    The deployment is being created.
    1 Instance: 1 Stopped

    Running
    Not all role instances are ready.
    1 Instance: 1 Stopped

    Running
    Not all role instances are ready.
    1 Instance: 1 Creating

    Running
    Not all role instances are ready.
    1 Instance: 1 Starting

    Running
    Not all role instances are ready.
    1 Instance: 1 Busy
```

So. How can I get this is message on powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't. As you know, both the portal and Windows Azure Cmdlets make use [`Service Management API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx) for deployment management. The operation responsible for returning this status is [`Get Operation Status`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460783.aspx). PowerShell Cmdlet for deployment makes use of this operation internally and only exits when it gets either a success or failure from this operation.

I haven't tried it personally (so I may be wrong) but you may want to look into [`Windows Azure Management Library`](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/getting-started-with-the-windows-azure-management-libraries). Like PowerShell Cmdlets, it is also a wrapper over Service Management API and it may have this capability.